# maven build error java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve target definition /home/gopithulasinathan/El/Git/dnobel_smarthome/smarthome/targetplatform/smarthome.target: Could not find "org.codehaus.groovy23.feature.feature.group/2.9.0.xx-201407142235-e44-RELEASE" in the repositories of the current location -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve target definition /home/gopithulasinathan/El/Git/dnobel_smarthome/smarthome/targetplatform/smarthome.target
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve target definition /home/gopithulasinathan/El/Git/dnobel_smarthome/smarthome/targetplatform/smarthome.target
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContent(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolverService.resolveFromArguments(TargetDefinitionResolverService.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolverService.getTargetDefinitionContent(TargetDefinitionResolverService.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.resolveTargetDefinitions(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.computeTargetPlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.facade.TargetDefinitionResolutionException: Could not find "org.codehaus.groovy23.feature.feature.group/2.9.0.xx-201407142235-e44-RELEASE" in the repositories of the current location
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.getUnitInstance(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContentWithExceptions(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContent(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:80)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the repository location at you target file (smarthome.target). It will look something like this with different version maybe :

```
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository/"/>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <unit id="org.codehaus.groovy23.feature.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
      <repository location="http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.4/"/>
    </location>
```